# asp.net core migrated project.json to csproj and now i can't build for linux/mac

Tags: linux, macos, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-1.1

I have migrated my project.json to csproj using the 'Dotnet migrate' command from the terminal. But now I can no longer build or publish my app for osx or Linux using a command like 'dotnet build -f osx.10.11-x64' when I run this it iutputs the following. I also don't think the csproj created by the migrate tool will create a self contained app which is what I had before by removing the 'type=platform' from the project.json.

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\1.0.0-rc4-004771\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\build\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets(84,5): error : Cannot infer TargetFrameworkIdentifier and/or TargetFrameworkVersion from TargetFramework='osx.10.11-x64'. They must be specified explicitly.
```

This is my csproj file that was created by the migrate command.

```
    <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
    <PreserveCompilationContext>true</PreserveCompilationContext>
    <AssemblyName>sample</AssemblyName>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <PackageId>Kosmele</PackageId>
    <RuntimeIdentifiers>osx.10.11-x64;ubuntu.16.04-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
    <RuntimeFrameworkVersion>1.0.3</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Update="wwwroot\**\*;web.config">
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics" Version="1.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel" Version="1.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console" Version="1.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Filter" Version="1.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables" Version="1.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions" Version="1.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="1.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine" Version="1.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="1.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Extensions.Logging.File" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="1.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following bare bones `.csproj` file (for a ASP.NET MVC project) worked for me on OS X.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="1.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="1.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="1.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink" Version="1.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```